# Antlr4 how to match something that I do not care about

Tags: antlr4

I am working on a parser that will have phases. On every phase it will analyze some data and will prepare it for the next phase. The input may have data already prepared for the next phase. I do not want to complicate the grammar for phase 1 with constructions from phase 2.

Or if I have a file that looks like this:

```
some complex constructions that I do not care at this phase about specifics
but I know that they will not have line starting with < 
...
...

< line: 0 foo bar
< line: 1 blah blah

more constructions

< line: 0 foo bar
< line: 1 blah blah
```

What my grammar should look like to parse the lines with a rule like this

```
line
    :   SERIALIZE_BRACKET KW_LINE 
        NUMBER        # indent
        .*?           # content 
        ( EOL | EOF ) # the end of the line
    ;
```

and everything else to be returned in a generic unknown blocks. Note I do not want the data to be skipped, I would like to be able to have access to it, I just do not want to parse it at this phase.

What my grammar should look like ... ?

Comment: What my grammar should look like ... ?

Comment: Search for "grammar islands antlr4". It's ideal for "mixed" grammars like Javascript in HTML etc. Seems like it's also suitable for your case.